# Store pandas_datareader into a new csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
def handle_data(symbol, start, end):
    stock_data = data.DataReader(
        symbol,
        'yahoo',
        start,
        end)

    return stock_data


x = handle_data(ticker, start=datetime(2021, 1, 2), end=datetime(2021, 2, 5))
```

This function returns this:

```
                  High         Low        Open       Close    Volume  \
Date                                                                   
2021-02-02  136.309998  134.610001  135.729996  134.990005  83305400   
2021-02-03  135.770004  133.610001  135.759995  133.940002  89880900   
2021-02-04  137.399994  134.589996  136.300003  137.389999  83946000   
2021-02-05  137.410004  135.860001  137.350006  136.759995  72317009
```

I want to make it so my python script can save stock historical data into a csv file so I can use it for later projects. I tried doing this with the csv module, but couldn't find anything that matches with what i am trying to do. Is there any way of storing this data into a new csv file without needing an existing one.

Comment: df.to_csv('out.csv') should be able write to a csv file

Answer (score 1):

You are one line of code away from the answer.

```
x.to_csv('mydata.csv', index = True)
```